# Use all eight weights of IBM Plex fonts in emacs (including "Text")

Tags: fonts

I was inspired by [Paul Ford](https://usesthis.com/interviews/paul.ford/) to use [IBMs font Plex](https://github.com/IBM/plex) for my emacs config. One of the strengths of IBM Plex is that all the four families  each have eight weights.

**The families:** *Mono, Sans, Sans Condensed, Serif*

**The weights:**  *Thin, Extra Light, Light, Regular, Text, Medium, SemiBold, Bold*

But I encounter three problems:

1. setting :weight text (in the customize-area)

   ```
   '(variable-pitch ((t (:family "IBM Plex Sans" :height 152 :weight text))))
     Error Message:
   Invalid face weight: text
   ```
2. medium and regular seem to be interpreted as the same font weight. At least nothing changes if I use :weight regular or :weight medium.
3. The font on regular looks different (heavier) in emacs than what I see on the "Typetester" (white button) on [the font's website](https://www.ibm.com/plex/#).

Is there a way to enable all the eight font weights for use in emacs?

I am fairly new to emacs.

Comment: manual says : "‘'weight’ One of ‘light’, ‘medium’, ‘demibold’, ‘bold’ or ‘black’." 
I'm no expert in this, but you may be looking for XLFD description, take a look at [fonts](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html#Fonts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maybe found an answer, although I cannot verify it from the output, I think that this hack has the desired effect of being able to use all the eight font weights.

First I pasted `(insert (prin1-to-string (x-list-fonts "*")))` into the *scratch* buffer (`Ctrl x` then `b` and type `*scratch*`)

Then I ran the command with `Ctrl j` at the end of the line  and it printed all the fonts. I did a bit of cleanup (I used `org-mode` with `query-replace` and `org-sort`) and got the following:

```
[...]
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-extralight-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-extralight-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-light-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-normal-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-normal-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-normal-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-semibold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-thin-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
[...]
```

I got similar output for each IBM Plex font. Interestingly there is three times the same font in XLFD style:

```
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" 
"-IBM -IBM Plex Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"
```

I suppose that "Medium" and "Text" are recognized as another "Normal" (Regular).

I experimented with the priorities in Org-Mode and formatted every priority in a different face to quickly see the differences when switching. I got the desired effect using the weight in `family` instead of `weight`. 
Following combinations worked for me (in the customize-section)

```
:family "IBM Plex Mono" :weight normal

:family "IBM Plex Mono Medium" :weight normal

:family "IBM Plex Mono Text" :weight normal
```

The intuitive way `:family "IBM Plex Mono" :weight medium` did not work.

**On my windows machine** I had to use the weight sometimes in the `family` AND the `weight` like:

```
:family "IBM Plex Mono SemiBold" :weight semibold
```

The weight just in the `family` with `:weight normal` did not work for me exept for "Text" and "Medium".

My experience was that not every weight in every font has an easy notable difference. But with this hack, I am able to apply all the desired font styles.